# How do I stream into a string without creating a named stringstream?

Tags: c++

I often end up writing code like this:

```
SomeStreamableType x;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Value is: " << x;
log(ss.str());
```

The extra line needed to generate the stringstream feels superfulous. I can do this, but it's equally cumbersom:

```
SomeStreamableType x;
const std::string str =  "Value is: " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x);
log(str);
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
SomeStreamableType x;
log(std::stringstream() << "Value is: " << x);
```

Have others encountered this issue and come up with a workaround? **I don't want to create any helper functions or classes**.

Comment: Creating helper functions and classes is precisely what C++ is all about. "I want my C++ program to do this and that, but I don't want to create any functions or classes." Right, that'll work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik He has a point that this is such a common operation that it would make sense for the standard library to provide a simple interface for it. Every programmer shouldn't have to roll their own.

Comment: What he/she said. If you're writing tools to do generic tasks, I'd say you're doing c++ wrong.

Comment: @quant I want a pony :(

Comment: But what would a "workaround" look like without using code of some variety? A function or a class is inevitable. You can't expect the Standard Library to have written every little possibility.

Comment: @Galik `log((std::stringstream() << "Value is: " << x).str())` would be nice. But it doesn't work because `<<` returns a `basic_ostream`. I don't think this is wishful thinking - almost looks like a bug in the standard to me...

Comment: @quant I would argue that there what you have there looks pretty cumbersome tbh. With more code there are nicer solutions for the end user. I suppose overloading insertion/extraction operators for `stringstream` might be nice for some things but I personally probably wouldn't use it for that.

Comment: Maybe `log(static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream() << "Value is: " << x)).str());`, but that kind of looks ugly, too.

Comment: @Galik yeah I agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will work without modifications, as long as `log` accepts an `ostream&` reference:

```
void log(ostream& o) {
    stringstream* s = dynamic_cast<stringstream*>(&o);
    if (s) {
        cout << s->str() << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 5, y = 6;
    log(stringstream() << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/wQW0ib)

Comment: That's cool. What if it's `void log(std::string)`? Can you somehow do a one-line `.str()` call on it? (I tried and failed).

Comment: @quant Unfortunately, that isn't going to work. That's what the `dynamic_cast` inside `log` is all about.

Comment: This seems like a Standard bug to me; why doesn't the `<<` operator from `stringstream` return a `stringstream`?

Comment: @quant There is no operator `<<` specifically for `stringstream`, there's one covering all `ostream`s. Perhaps making `operator <<` a template returning its first parameter wouldn't hurt, but standard writers made a different decision.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem I have often simply done something like this:

```
#define LOG(m) do{std::ostringstream oss;oss<<m;std::cout<<oss.str()<<'\n';}while(0)

// ...

LOG("some text: " << value1 << ' ' << value2); // no need for '\n'
```

Now I tend to use a more sophisticated class based solution that has an even nicer interface and doesn't use a horrible macro.